# Sync scroll navigation and content with flexible heights

Tags: javascript

I have a menu on the left and articles on the right. The number of menu items and article items is indefinite.

For example the first menu-item has a height of 100px.
The first article has a height of 300px.

When article 1 has been scrolled 300px i want the menu-item-1 to be scrolled 100px. I have the code below, which sync scrolls the menu, but not correctly. How can I calculate the height of each item and pass the scroll to article-2 and menu-item-2 which have different heights and so on?

```
let menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item");
let menuHeight = sectionMenu.scrollHeight;
let articleItems = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
let articleHeight = articleItems.scrollHeight;
    
sectionContent.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const scrolledContent = sectionContent.scrollTop;
  sectionMenu.scroll(0, scrolledContent / articleHeight * menuHeight);
})
```